# Where to locate a chatbox in a 2D or 3D interface?

Tags: interface, chat

I'm wondering if anyone has any evidence or experience to base myself on when locating a chatbox on a website and if possible in a 3D virtual world?

Are there any case studies covering the best positions on the screen or whether it's best to have them fixed somewhere (life Facebook) or floating and you can move them around.

I've been searching but all I get is how to implement them :(

Comment: I think chatboxes are more or less aesthetic to the web page their in. In Facebook chatting should be present always throughout the site as its one of their major components. A Floating chatbox on a website? Not really seen that that often. Chatboxes don't really need to move round the screen so why give the user the option. Just my two cents

Answer (score 2):

One of the best systems for 3D chat I've seen had the replies actually appear over the heads of the avatars representing the speaker in-game.  I thought this was great design, but also great immersion.  Graphical [MMORPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmorpg)s often do this.

As for 2D interfaces, I feel the best design is one that unobtrusive at first, such as in a bottom bar.   It should have the ability to be pulled out into a separate window, and returned if needed.  That way, you can match whatever paradigm your users are most comfortable with.